# how would i add an array of post types in this code?

Tags: php

`$nopages = "AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'post'";`

In addition to the `post` post type, I'd like to add a couple more (i.e. 'projects' and 'videos'). I'm not much of a coder so I'm not sure where to begin. Can I add something like `'post_type' => array( 'post','videos','projects' ),` anywhere in there?

Comment: Could you post some more code? What exactly is $nopages for? Does it serve as part of an SQL query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use **`IN()`** in your SQL query :

```
"AND $wpdb->posts.post_type IN ('post','videos','projects')";
```

And, if you have those in a PHP array, like this :

```
$types = array('post','videos','projects');
```

You can use the [**`implode()`**](https://www.php.net/implode) to concatenate them into a string that can be used in an SQL query :

```
$types_in = implode(', ', $types);
"AND $wpdb->posts.post_type IN ($types_in)";
```